# slickgrid get data from invisible selected rows

Tags: slickgrid

When filter is applied on selected rows hidden selected rows are not getting using  getSelectedrows().It only returns selected rows which are visible.Searched alot couldn't get one.Need data of selected rows which are visible and invisible.

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: This question looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217173/slickgrid-select-rows-while-filter-is-on-forgets-previous-selections Did you try the solution they found?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [slickgrid select rows while filter is on forgets previous selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217173/slickgrid-select-rows-while-filter-is-on-forgets-previous-selections)

Comment: Thanks all..Found solution tat link solves a part

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#synchronizing-selection--cell-css-styles

*Quote:*

One of the most common questions about DataView is how to synchronize the selection or cell CSS styles state on DataView changes. Let's say that the user selected a row. If they then change the filter on the DataView to hide some items, the grid gets a call to invalidate all changed rows, including the selected one, but it doesn't know that the item that was displayed there has moved somewhere else. What we need to do, is to store the ids of items that were selected, and to update the selection on the grid any time the DataView is modified.

Luckily, there is a helper method on the DataView that can take care of that:

`syncGridSelection(grid, preserveHidden)` - Synchronizes grid's selected rows with the DataView by subscribing to the grid's onSelectedRowsChanged event as well as the DataView's onRowsChanged & onRowCountChanged events. If preserveHidden is true, it will preserve selected items even if they are not visible as rows. For example, if you select an item, change the DataView filter so that that item is no longer presented to the grid and then change it back, the item will remain selected. If preserveHidden is false, all selected items that can't be mapped onto rows are dropped.
The implementation is really simple, and I'll include it here for the reference:

```
function syncGridSelection(grid, preserveHidden) {
  var self = this;
  var selectedRowIds = self.mapRowsToIds(grid.getSelectedRows());;
  var inHandler;

  function update() {
    if (selectedRowIds.length > 0) {
      inHandler = true;
      var selectedRows = self.mapIdsToRows(selectedRowIds);
      if (!preserveHidden) {
        selectedRowIds = self.mapRowsToIds(selectedRows);
      }
      grid.setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
      inHandler = false;
    }
  }

  grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    if (inHandler) { return; }
    selectedRowIds = self.mapRowsToIds(grid.getSelectedRows());
  });

  this.onRowsChanged.subscribe(update);

  this.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(update);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...This one works but,this is not the solution im looking  for .Thing is syncgridselection function has added two more parameters check with tat if anyone needs tat I can  put here.you need set true to multiselect to preserve when hidden and another call back function which will return the selectedIds.you can do the stuff you need.dont use onselectedrowschanged when u try to do action with hidden selected rows bcuz, callback works after onselectedrowschanged.thanks...!